# How to upload a file to OneDrive using OneDrive REST API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, file-upload, onedrive

Please allow me to explain **what** I am doing and **How** I am doing.

**What I am doing?**

I am trying to upload a file to Onedrive using its REST API
Source: [one drive api documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm)

I am using OneDrive fragments approch to do so as the file can be as huge as 5gb or as small as 1kb (Depends on the user)

Currently, I am doing it using [POST-MAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) Chrome extention to call APIes

**How am I doing?**

1. Generated Access token
2. Created Session and received Uploading url
3. Uploading file using PUT request as given below

Selected file that I want to upload *(File Size: 729676295 bytes)*
[image]

Added headers and sent the request and sent the request
[image]
**Here is the result**
[image]

it is saying that the maximum fragment size is 67108864 bytes so I changed the value of

**content-length : 67108864** and
**content-range : bytes 0-67108863/729676295**

but then I get this error message: **Declared fragment length does not match the provided number of bytes**
[image]

***Please help me to figure out what should I pass in content-length and content-range.***

Many Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, thanks to god after 2 days of struggle I found what was the problem.

There are some points that you need to keep in mind

1. You have to divide a file to into equal parts and save it somewhere and upload each of them separately on the same URL that you get after creating a session.
2. **Content-Length** must be the total numbers of bytes of the file that you are uploading in all upload requests of fragments.
3. **Content-Range** will be like: **0-{fragmentLength-1}/{totalNumberOfBytesOfFile}**(same as *content-length*) and from next fragment the **Content-Range** will be **{uploadedBytes}-{uploadedBytes+nextSetOfBytes-1}/{totalNumberOfBytesOfFile}**

**Note:** The Next set of bytes should be as long as the previous was. Do not worry because the last fragment can be different.

P.S: Do not use the content-range that you will receive after successfully uploading the fragment.

Comment: Hi your solution solved my problem as well thank you

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`{totalNumberOfBytesOfFile}` is not same as `content-length`;

`Content-Length` is bytes of current fragment.

the image is an a example for upload a 4917 bytes file.